# `Pacman` rollback or fixing a disappeared KDE taskbar?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, pacman

I upgraded my ArchLinux installation yesterday and one of the packages affected was KDE. After restarting, the taskbar has disappeared and I have found no way to make it reappear. Is there a mirror with older packages (to rollback) or a way to fix the problem?

Comment: It's probably some stupid kde ate my config... stuff... check [this previous answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3803/messed-up-bottom-panel-fedora-14-kde/3812#3812), if it solves your problem please let me know as I think this is a duplicate

Comment: Yes, partially...i cant restore system tray. It crashes loses and the changes I ve made in this session

Comment: yeah how kde writes configs is stupid... um... change it and log out immediately.. ? does that fix it?

Comment: i dont get you...change what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that KDE is a group of packages and when upgrading with `pacman` it would typically upgrade individual packages in that group. Look in `/var/log/pacman.log` to see exactly which packages that were upgraded.

You should be able to downgrade the package that source your problem there, by locating the previous version of the package in 
`/var/cache/pacman/pkg/<pkg_name>-<ver>-<arch>.pkg.tar.xz`.

From there your simply install the old version with

```
# pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/<pkg_name>-<ver>-<arch>.pkg.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea about fixing the problem, but you'll find lots of information regarding downgrading packages [in the ArchWiki's "Downgrading Packages" section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_Packages#How_to_downgrade_a_package); both using possible cached versions and [with older packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_Packages#Finding_Your_Older_Version).

Comment: I like the sclinux.org solution, provided in the wiki. But how can I downgrade the whole kde? :s

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. After some time I found [this page](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.arch.general/37440) where appeared to have a similar problem.

After reading it, this was what I did to solve it in my archlinux system:

```
$ # Backup files 'plasma-desktoprc' and 'plasma-desktop-appletsrc'  
$ find ~ -type f -iname "*plasma-desktop*" -exec cp -v {} {}.old \;  
# reboot
```